# How to get rank tied scores?

Tags: php

Everyone. I am new here and also a new programmer in PHP. I am building a ranking, and want you guys to help me with rank ties because, in my attempt to find the perfect ranking solution with ties, I was stuck at giving the correct ranking. Codes will explain what I am trying to achieve better:

```
<?php
if ($dados == "") {
    $totalWebservice1 = 0;
    $position = 1;
    $mat = '';
    $id = '';
    foreach ($resultAll as $dado) {
        $group = $insert->selectGrupo($dado['codClient']);
        if ($dado['codClient'] == $group['id_sponte'] && $group['group'] == 'yellow' && $topOne['codClient'] != $dado['codClient']) {
            $totalWebservice1 = $totalWebservice1 + $dado['registration'];
            ?>
            <tr>

                <td><?php echo $position?>º</td>
                <td><?php echo $dado['name'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dado['registration'] ?></td>
                <?php
                if ($dado['registration'] != $mat || $dado['name'] != $id) { // if not the same id.
                    $position++;
                }
                ?>
            </tr>

            <?php
            $mat = $dado['registration'];
            $id = $dado['name'];
        }
    }
} else {
    $totalMatriculas1 = 0;
?>
```

Output:

```
Position Name      Registration
1°       teste       4
2°       teste       2
3°       teste       2
3°       teste       2
3°       teste       2
3°       teste       1
```

Expected Output:

```
Position Name      Registration
1°       teste       4
2°       teste       2
2°       teste       2
2°       teste       2
2°       teste       2
3°       teste       1
```

The problem is it prints the ranking as `1,2,3,3,3,3` whereas it should print `1,2,2,2,2,3` according to my assumption. So how can it print `1,2,2,3`? Where could thing possibly go wrong?

Comment: Please post _all_ relevant code (which includes the loop). There are variables in there we have no idea how or where they were populated.

Comment: Sorry man, so I have added the whole code again.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement is after the echo, so you are preparing it for the next iteration and that is why the count is one-off.

Besides that, the logic is a bit flaky. Try to avoid 'do nothing' situations.

```
if ($dado['registration'] != $mat || $dado['name'] != $id) { // if not the same id.
    $position++; 
}
```

Comment: Daan, Thank you so much, you got it.